# How to create a HotOrNot/FaceMash site with Django based on the Poll tutorial?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have gone through Django's basic Poll tutorial, and I realize that I can change some things here and there and make a HotOrNot/FaceMash style site out of it. However, since I'm still a noob, I can only come up with the concept of it - there's no way for me to know how to do it. So the concept is that instead of displaying all the choices for the poll, display only two random choices(which should not be the same). Also, there needs to be a way to bulk upload from computer or fetch from an external storage/server all the images as choices to the poll. Could anyone tell me how to make this happen? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not clear but let's give a try.
I guess you want to compare 2 random photos, and let the user choose which is the best.
I think of one simple way to do this, not necessarily with the poll app.

First, create a model to store images. For example:

```
class Image(models.Model):
  picture = models.ImageField("Face picture", max_length=255, upload_path=<your upload path function>)
```

Then instead of using poll, make your own:

```
class Match(models.Model):
  winner = models.ForeignKey('yourapp.Image')
  loser = models.ForeignKey('yourapp.Image')
```

Make your forms and save the results of the poll in a Match instance.
To know how many times a picture has been shown, just look for Match rows where winner or loser is the picture:

```
times_shown = Match.objects.filter(Q(winner=pic)|Q(loser=pic)).count()
```

Then the same applies to know how much a picture is popular. If it is often a winner, then you can assume it has good looks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a few questions about your code, though.

Comment: Oops. anyway, so my question is: isn't ImageField used for uploading images? Or is it also used for displaying images? Say I already have all the images that are uploaded by users stored in the database, so the only thing I need to do is just display 2 random images from the database and record the votes.

Comment: ImageField is used to upload images indeed, then you can display them. If your images are already in a folder visible from the internet, you can also a URLField instead, which you can populate with the URLs to the pictures.
If the images are uploaded and stored in the database, you're right, just display 2 random images and a radio form. Then you save the vote result, putting the selected picture in the __winner__ attribute, and putting the other one in __loser__.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. Thanks a lot!